# MySQL Insert Into datetime = NOW() is not working?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following code (php, mysql, pdo):

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO agent_temp SET party=?, date = NOW()");
$stmt->execute(array($party));
```

when run, the party is insert correctly but the date is not inserting as it should (the system date and time at action). I have verified numerous times the field type for date is datetime.

Any ideas?

## EDIT

To give actual data and the results returned:

assume the following:

$party = 'John';

the results return:

```
party      |      date    
-------------------------------------
John       |    0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

update:

When i run the following code directly within a mysql query browser, the insert works just as it should:

insert into agent_temp set party = 'John', date = NOW();

returning:

```
party      |      date    
-------------------------------------
John       |    2010-12-28 13:15:23
```

### ANSWERED

Well, who is ready to kill me? I have no idea what caught it up but unfortunately the issue seemingly was due to an earlier version of the php script from my machine being cached and still running bad data. I refreshed, closed, and emptied my browser and now the script works. My apologies for making everybody's brains melt just a little.

Comment: What do you mean "not updating as it should"? What do you think it should be doing? What is it doing instead?

Comment: What is inserting instead? Could you please run the code and post the newly inserted record here?

Comment: nothing - that is the confusion here. Party field inserts correctly. Date field SHOULD insert the date/time stamp at the time of action but it is not.

Comment: @JM4: `MySQL` inserts data record-wise, you can't insert one field without another. What do you see in the `date` column of the newly inserted record?

Comment: @JM4: is `party` a primary key? Are you sure you are looking at the right record? Could you please post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE agent_temp` here?

Comment: @JM4: Have you tried [SYSDATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sysdate)? All signs point to a column-type mismatch, however (given what you _have_ told us).

Comment: @JM4: Also, try not using SET in your INSERT, use the (imho) more traditional method: `INSERT INTO table (column1,column2) VALUES (value1,value2);`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO agent_temp SET party=?, date = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($_POST['party'], date("Y-m-d H:i:s")));
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, while I know this WILL work, so should my statement above so more than trying to figure out how to fix it, I am trying to understand why the above statement does not insert the current timestamp as it "should"

Comment: Could be a PDO parsing issue or something... I'm gonna try and replicate the problem. What system/setup are you using?

Comment: was a browser caching issue unfortunately. Thank you for your suggestion. I will go ahead and accept your answer though as it is 'correct' given somebody wanted to go that route.

Comment: haha, no worries mate. I've had the same thing happen to me more than once!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure which system you are using, but I would think your prepare statement will be adding quotation around the `NOW()` part - causing the statement to try and insert *NOW()* instead of running the mysql function `NOW()` - thus because the field can't store the characters *NOW()* you get the 000-00.....

Out of interest, try changing the field type from `DATETIME` to `TEXT` and see what you get when you run the command.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pure `INSERT` statement, it does not update any rows.

Comment: understood, the syntax in my question was wrong, now updated. My point being the insert statement is not inserting a date/time at all.

Comment: @JM4: could you please run the code and post the newly inserted record here?

Answer (score 1):

Untested but perhaps the problem is that 'date' is a reserved word, you could try renaming your column and see if it works.

The other approach is to add a timestamp-field with an 'ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'.

Comment: good suggestion but 'date' is not the actual name of the field. I trimmed down my actual statement for reference but this does not work.

Comment: on update also does not work in this field's need (changes to the row would/should not update this field)

Comment: On reflection: as you don't update the ON UPDATE isn't necessary. But I'll leave it in for whenever you feel like updating :)